# Swagger does not shown a List of Enum's in the modelview

Tags: java, generics, swagger

I have the following code in an Abstract `@ApiModel` class:

```
@ApiModelProperty(required = false)
private List<V> requestedCovers;
```

Where `V` is a Generic Type, defined as  `V extends Enum<V> & CoverType`. I have various classes that extend this Abstract class for different implementations.

In the Swagger UI Model, it shows as follows:

```
requestedCovers (Array[string], optional)
```

Why are the enum options for this implementation not shown?

For comparison, I have also a List of Objects with an enum value in the object which works fine in the same structure:

```
@ApiModelProperty(required = false)
private List<OwnRisk<U>> ownRisks;
```

Where `U` is `U extends Enum<U> & ORType`. There the Swagger UI Model shows:

```
ownRisks (Array[OwnRiskHearingAidORType], optional)
```

and

```
OwnRiskHearingAidORType {
    type (string, optional): The type. = ['GENERIC'],
    value (number, optional): The value.
}
```

So here I see the enum value that are present for this (in this case hearing aid implementeation)

Comment: X-Posted TO: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/issues/1928

Comment: Can you provide more info of your class model ORType and CoverType and other classes.

Comment: `ORType` an `CoverType` are interfaces that implement different types. In this case the enum's `HearingAidORType` and HearingAidCoverType`